# Timezone parsing inferno

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this ISO date:

```
var v = '2013-07-09T13:27:29.000Z';
```

If I do this:

```
var g = moment(v).format();
```

Console gives me g value as the correct local time **2013-07-08T17:25:08-03:00**

But if I do this to get the time ago:

```
console.log(moment(g).startOf('day').fromNow());
```

Moments calculates the time ago using original v ISO instead of the formatted g.

Why?

Edit: I have tested another time plugin (jquery.timeago) and the same error parsing to local time happens when passing the original v value.

What am I doing wrong here? This code is being executed on client side, so all plugins *were supposed to* return the correct local time for the user.

**Edit 2**: More relevant info on what I'm trying to do:

```
var v = notifs.ntime; //2013-07-09T13:27:29.000Z
var m = moment(v).zone(v).format(); // 2013-07-09T13:27:29+00:00 (wrong local)
var m2 = moment(v).format();  // 2013-07-09 10:27:29 (correct local)
var r = moment(v).zone(v).startOf('day').fromNow() // 21 hours ago (wrong)
var r2 = moment(v).startOf('day').fromNow() // 18 hours ago (wrong)
console.log(v);
console.log(m);
console.log(m2);
console.log(r);
console.log(r2);
console.log('-------------------');
/*
    2013-07-09T13:27:29.000Z                            
    2013-07-09T13:27:29+00:00                           
    2013-07-09T10:27:29-03:00                           
    21 hours ago                        
    18 hours ago                            
    -------------------

    I expected "8 hours ago" as now is 18:10 and (v) was set on 10:27 (m2)
*/
```

Comment: did you try using the moment(g, format) function yet where you can specify the format of your input? maybe your browser or wherever you use momentjs can't handle the resulting string ```2013-07-08T17:25:08-03:00``` correctly, although it looks okay to me...

Comment: Yeap, tried that as well. Testing the g var using moment(g).isValid() returns true. This is really annoying.

Comment: @luksch - FYI, moment formats ISO strings independently of the browser.  So it's not a compatibility or formatting issues.

Comment: @MattJohnson Yes! I want it relative to local time. The fromNow() does not work that way?

Comment: Yes, it does already work that way.  If you are seeing other results, then please show exactly what you are getting and what time zone you are in.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, `fromNow()` just subtracts and formats for output.  It's `startOf('day')` that will be affected by whether the moment is in local or utc mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I follow what you're looking for.

By using your `g` variable, you are essentially doing this:

```
moment(moment(v).format()).startOf('day').fromNow()
```

That is a bit redundant.  It is the exact same thing as this:

```
moment(v).startOf('day').fromNow()
```

That will tell you how much time has passed between now and the start of the *local* day that `v` fell on.

If you are looking for how much time as passed between now and the start of the *UTC* day that `v` fell on, then use this instead:

```
moment.utc(v).startOf('day').fromNow()
```

Or using a slightly different syntax, but identical in effect:

```
moment(v).utc().startOf('day').fromNow()
```

If you were looking for something else, please clarify.

#### Walkthrough

Let's walk through what happens when I run your original code on my computer.  I am in Arizona, USA, which is at UTC-7 with no daylight saving time.

```
// we'll start with the string you provided
var v = '2013-07-09T13:27:29.000Z';

// and the redundant moment, but we'll take a look at the formatting
var g = moment(v).format();

console.log(g);                 // 2013-07-09T06:27:29-07:00
console.log(moment(g).format()) // 2013-07-09T06:27:29-07:00  (it didn't change)

// start of the local day is midnight in the local time zone
console.log(moment(g).startOf('day').format())  // 2013-07-09T00:00:00-07:00

// here's my time right now
console.log(moment().format())  // 2013-07-09T13:56:54-07:00

// and your final bit of code
console.log(moment(g).startOf('day').fromNow());  // 14 hours ago
```

As you can see it is performing correctly, using the local time zone when determining the start of day.  Of course, when you run this in a different time zone, it is going to return different results.  That's because every time zone has it's own concept of each day.  If you wanted consistent output, then you would remove the `startOf('day')` call.

#### Recommendation

After your last update stating that you expected 8 hours, then it seems you didn't really want the time from the `startOf('day')` at all.  Just do this:

```
moment(v).fromNow()
```

There's no need to involve the `.zone()` either.

Comment: Thanks, I will check your walkthrough! Meanwhile, I have edited my question providing sample output commands and returned data!

Comment: Thank you Matt, startOf('day') was indeed the bad guy. For some reason I thought that I needed that to use fromNow(). That was *very* annoying, thanks!